# How to create a matrix from CSV in python?

Tags: python, csv, matrix

Following this, I'd like to populate the matrix: (this is where I get stuck). I'd like to populate that matrix using like, data in the 4th column in that CSV file but wasn't able to. Was thinking of writing it to a output excel file.

```
    for i in readcsv:.........
```

However, everything (most things) that I do seem to go wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try and use [panda](http://pandas.pydata.org/), specifically this function, [as_matrix()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.as_matrix.html), to convert it to a matrix/array:

If you're completely new to panda, their [tutorial](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/10min.html) is pretty good and doesn't take long!

You can read [from a csv](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html#pandas.read_csv) which will return a [DataFrame](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.html). From that dataframe you can use the function, [as_matrix()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.as_matrix.html), I listed earlier.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I'll try it out and see what I can do :).